# Adding the randomly picked numbers

Tags: python, random, sum

The following code gives me the random picks from the list of numbers.

```
import random
print ('Your five random numbers are')
for i in range(1):
print (random.sample([10,12,14,15,17,24,27,30,32,35,38,39,42,45,46,47],5))
```

The output is:

```
Your five random numbers are
[39, 10, 15, 38, 24]
```

In the output above they sum up to 126. How can I get python to calculate this sum?

Comment: The indentation is wrong, but what possible reason do you have for the "loop" `for i in range(1):`?

Comment: John,that is the way I can request more than one set. When I change the range() say to 3 I get 3 sets and so on. I am new to this , last programming I did was at the Uni 30 years ago in Fortran 77 and Pascal :-(

Answer (score 1):

Something like that?

```
import random

numbers = random.sample([10,12,14,15,17,24,27,30,32,35,38,39,42,45,46,47],5)

print("Your five random numbers are {}".format(numbers))

total = 0
for i, n in enumerate(numbers):
    total += n

print("The sum is {}".format(total))
```

The output of a sample run is:

```
Your five random numbers are [32, 24, 45, 38, 15]
The sum is 154
```

Or by using directly the sum function:

```
import random

numbers = random.sample([10,12,14,15,17,24,27,30,32,35,38,39,42,45,46,47],5)

print("Your five random numbers are {}".format(numbers))

total = sum(numbers)
print("The sum is {}".format(total))
```

#### Addition

The OP asked also to loop along this procedure and keep only sets that have sum in the range (123, 143), without adding any additional constraint. I will loop to find an N number of sets:

```
import random
# List of number
pool = [10,12,14,15,17,24,27,30,32,35,38,39,42,45,46,47]
# This will contain the selcted list
picked = []
# This will contain the selcted list sums
picked_totals = []
# Number of selected list of random numbers
N = 10

while len(picked) <= N:
    numbers = random.sample(pool, 5)
    total = sum(numbers)
    if total > 123 and total < 143:
        picked.append(numbers)
        picked_totals.append(total)

print("Result")
for i, e in enumerate(picked):
    print("{} :: {} (sum {})".format(i, e, picked_totals[i]))
```

Comment: That did it Mateo, great answer! Now how could I go about looping it to only keep picked sets that sum 123<sum<143? So if the sum is outside these boundaries discard it and draw another set, print only sets that the sum falls within this range?